# difference in ./my_code.py or python3 my_code.py

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have below code:

my_code.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

print("content-type: text/html")
print()

x=5

print("hello world")
```

When I run with  `python3 my_code.py` it executed and output as expected

```
content-type: text/html

hello world
```

but if I run with `./` then it says syntax error :

```
./my_code.py 
./my_code.py: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `"content-type: text/html"'
./my_code.py: line 4: `print("content-type: text/html")'
```

Comment: It sounds like your `#!` line isn't working. Is it definitely the first line in your script?

Comment: "syntax error near unexpected token" is a Bash error. Are you sure you're not accidentally running `. my_code.py` (aka `source my_code.py`), which would be running it in your shell?

Comment: It says line 4 but in your code the print statement is on line 3, is there an empty line at the top of the file?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, when you use `./my_code.py` to run the file, it is not being executed by the python interpreter. The command `python3 my_code.py` explicitly tells your OS to run the file with the python interpreter, executing the file correctly. Using only `./file_name.extension`, executes the file using the default program specified for that file name, which might be the terminal for you in this case. But if the terminal does not contain a python interpreter, it will simply read the python code as invalid syntax giving you the syntax errors.

Furthermore, at the top of the file you specified `#!/usr/bin/python3`.

This is a [Shebang line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) which tells the OS where the interpreter is located. But if you're not running the file on Linux, or the interpreter is located elsewhere, it will still try to execute the file in the shell/terminal, which is giving you the syntax errors.

Answer (score -1):

i used shebang as #!/usr/bin/env python3